# Excel default date when dd/mm entered

Tags: microsoft-excel, date

In Excel when i enter a date into a blank cell (General format) as, say 7/15, the cell changes it's format to "Custom: m-ddd".  How can i make doing this default to the standard default date "*3/14/12"?
Note: my region "Short date" format is the standard U.S. "M/d/yy".

Comment: Have you checked your language settings in excel: `Option` > `Language` > `Editing language`, `Display language` and `Help language`. Also try to enter the date in a brand new excel file/sheet and see what happens. Tell us the results of the above, and if the error persists

Comment: Try to format date first.

Comment: Settings: Editing Language "English (United States) <default>"
Display Language: "Match Microsoft Windows <default>
Yes, it happens in a New worksheet.  
(BTW i consider myself quite knowledgeable in Excel, have been using it for decades and written many VBA macros. I'm not bragging, just letting you all know where i'm coming from.)

Comment: Yes, if the cell format is pre-set as "M/d/yy" then entering the date as 7/15 comes out correctly as 7/15/19.  But i don't understand why typing 7/15 into a "general" cell won't come out this way also.  Is this dd-mmm hard coded into Excel or is there a setting somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Can you not use the 'Cell format - Date' ? Right click on the cell and then format, go to date.[image: date excel 16]

Comment: yes i can but i want to get it to default to that format.  I can also enter 7/15/19 and it comes out in that format but the point is why do i have to go through those extra steps/keystrokes when that is supposed to be the default.

Comment: You can do a macro that does all those keystrokes for you - then assign it to either a toolbar button or a keyboard shortcut. Excel does it's default date the same as the profile language settings - These can be heavily adjusted to display the date how you want it

Comment: *Excel does it's default date the same as the profile language settings.*  Where are the **profile language settings**?  In the US, I have under Region Settings, a Region dialog with Language preferences showing a Short Date format of `M/d/yyyy`.  But when I type `7/15` into an Excel cell formatted as `General`, it will display as `15-Jul` with the cell number format having been changed from `General` to `d-mmm` (The date in the formula bar is `7/15/2019` but how can I control that initial change in Format from `General` to `d-mmm`?